# jQuery in mvc application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

How to use jQuery in mvc 2 application for fetching data from database using datatable?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not allow you to fetch data directly from database. In order to receive such data you have to make an Ajax call to your backend class (controller). Controller can call model, which can retrieve and maybe prepare needed data. Then you just return it (JSON format is preferable).

Answer (score 0):

I think your objective is to show a tabular data on the UI.  If i'm right, then can you try using JqGrid? As Ventus said, Json format is preferable

Comment: for more information, you can refer to this url, sample jqGrid demos and source code is also provided.  http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Unless you're replying to someone else's comment on your answer, you might as well just edit your answer instead of commenting on it. Click the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5340004/edit) link in the lower left-hand corner.

Answer (score 0):

HI,
you have to create ajax that talks to your controller and fetch data from the controller. This way you have control. I do not thing you can do it straing, unless you have some flash app with everything encoded inside, tho this is not wise.

Use controller and pass results to your front end app

Answer (score 0):

install nuget package `Install-Package jquery.datatables` for datatable refer to : https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.datatables

imlpement datatable like :
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html